# Generate Link based on the first Characters of a string of text

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, character

I am trying to generate a link for tracking numbers, but i need to generate the correct link based on the first character of the tracking number.

For example, If the Tracking # begins with 1Z - I need a UPS Link to be generated. If it begins with a 9, I need a USPS Link to be generated. And if it begins with a 7, I need a FedEx Link to be generated. Is there anyway with scripts that this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it can be done with javascript

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring()` to chop either the first two or first letters of a string and do a comparison

```js
var trackingNumber = "1Z9999999999999999"

var ups = 'http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums='
var usps = 'https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?qtc_tLabels1='
var fedEx = 'https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/WTRK/index.html?action=track&trackingnumber='

if(trackingNumber.substring(0, 2) == '1Z')
  var link = ups + trackingNumber

if(trackingNumber.substring(0, 1) == '9')
  var link = usps + trackingNumber

if(trackingNumber.substring(0, 1) == '7')
  var link = fedEx + trackingNumber

document.getElementById('tracking-link').href = link
```

```html
<a id="tracking-link">Tracking Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function (value) {
    if (value == 1Z) {
        return link1
    } else if (value == 9) {
        return link2
    } else if (value == 7) {
        return link3
    }
}
var link1 = UPS
var link2 = USPS
var link3 = FedEx

function CalculateValues(value) {
    return CalculateValues(value);
}
```